# How to dynamically iterate variables imported from yaml file in robot framework

Tags: yaml, robotframework

Below is the device_details.yaml file we use for variables,

```
Device1:
  IP: 192.168.23.21
  Port: 23
  admin_cred:
    username: admin
    password: Cisco123$
  nonadmin_cred:
    username: six 
    password: six

Device2:
  IP: 192.168.23.22
  Port: 23
  admin_cred:
    username: admin
    password: Cisco123$
  nonadmin_cred:
    username: six
    password: six
```

Below is the robot snippet:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    /tmp/robot/device_details.yaml

*** Test Case ***
Test
    Device Detail
***Keywords****
Device Detail
       Log   Device1 IP is ${Device1.IP}
       Log   Device1 port is ${Device1.Port}
       Log   Device1 admin username is ${Device1.admin_cred.username}
       Log   Device1 admin password is ${Device1.admin_cred.password}
       Log   Device1 non-admin username is ${Device1.nonadmin_cred.username}
       Log   Device1 non-admin password is ${Device1.nonadmin_cred.password}
       Log   Device2 IP is ${Device2.IP}
       Log   Device2 port is ${Device2.Port}
       Log   Device2 admin username is ${Device2.admin_cred.username}
       Log   Device2 admin password is ${Device2.admin_cred.password}
       Log   Device2 non-admin username is ${Device2.nonadmin_cred.username}
       Log   Device2 non-admin password is ${Device2.nonadmin_cred.password}
```

We might end up having 200 to 300 device details in the yaml file. 
Instead of calling each variable, is there any way to iterate the variables dynamically once after the another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach depends on how you want to test your devices and register the results. If you are always testing every device, then looping inside Robot Framework as shown below. However, using the command line arguments you can also load a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file). You would then use your test orchestration to loop through your device(s).

**devices.yaml**

```
Devices:
  a1:
    IP: 192.168.23.21

  b2:
    IP: 192.168.23.22
```

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

Variables    devices.yaml

*** Test Case ***

    Test
        ${device_names}    Get Dictionary Keys    ${devices}
        FOR    ${device}    IN    @{device_names}
           Log   Device1 IP is ${devices}[${device}][IP]
        END
```

Comment: Thanks Kootstra , That helped. Is it possible to create testcases dynamically based on the each device  IP - ${devices}[${device}][IP] . Currently In a single testcase, with your solution, we can loop through and pass IP address to function and execute it, but all the devices are tested under single testcase via looping. problem is there might be 10 device or may be 300 device to test. My employer wants to have separate test case for each device. Thanks.

Comment: Invariably the answer in IT will be "Yes", and/or "It Depends" when someone asks if something is feasible. The above answer highlights that you can use orchestration tools to cycle through a set of options that use external variable file(s) as input. You can combine this with Robot Framework Tags to filter out those testcases that are not required in a particular scenario.